# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML Inside Fragment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a use-case where I need to format some text in React and also render HTML.

Here is an example of what I'm currently trying to achieve:

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
import {renderToString} from "react-dom/server";

function FormatText(props) {
  const lines = props.children.split('\n');

  return lines.map((line, index) => (
    <Fragment key={index}>
      {line}{index !== lines.length - 1 && <br/>}
    </Fragment>
  ));
}

const content = {
  first: 'This is some text\nwith new\n\nline characters - 1',
  second: 'This is some text\nwith new\n\nline <strong>characters - <sup>2</sup></strong>',
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ol>
      <li>
        <FormatText>{content.first}</FormatText>
      </li>
      <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: renderToString(<FormatText>{content.second}</FormatText>)
      }}/>
    </ol>
  )
}
```

As you can see, I have some `content` which contains `\n` characters and HTML. Calling the `renderToString` function converts the HTML into encoded characters, which means the HTML is not rendered properly.

Is there a way to render HTML inside a react fragment.

Ideally I wanted to do the following (but it doesn't):

```
function FormatText(props) {
  const lines = props.children.split('\n');

  return lines.map((line, index) => (
    <Fragment key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: renderToString(
        <Fragment>
          {line}{index !== lines.length - 1 && <br/>}
        </Fragment>
      )}}>
    </Fragment>
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `<Fragment>` *doesn't adds any node to DOM* and so *`you can't do dangerouslySetInnerHTML on it`*. It is basically a functionality provided by React to avoid addition of extra node to DOM when you needed to return more than one from return in render. **So, if something doesn't exists on real DOM, you can't do anything on it**.
- `renderToString` is generally used on node server. When doing server side rendering, you want to send the html from server to client. So, better avoid `renderToString` also.

The issue is that, html doesn't recognises `\n` for new line etc. It needs *html* tags. The approach to use `FormatText` is fine or you can simply `convert the \n to br` and then use dangerouslySetInnerHTML inside the `<li>` tag.

```js
const content = {
  first: 'This is some text\nwith new\n\nline characters - 1',
  second: 'This is some text\nwith new\n\nline <strong>characters - <sup>2</sup></strong>',
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ol>
      <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: content.first.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")
      }}/>
      <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: content.second.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")
      }}/>
    </ol>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: I didn't think about using `String.prototype.replace` good choice

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess it is not possible, only way hot to pass formated html into DOm is via dom element DIV.

Maybe this link could help you or point to 
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html